# Calculation with Khatri rao product and moore penrose pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, kronecker-product

It is given:

$ \left [(A\diamond B\diamond C)^T  \right ]^\dagger$

$\diamond$ is Kharti -rao product

$\dagger$ -moore penrose pseudoinverse

**I have started:**

$ \left [(A\diamond B\diamond C)^T  \right ]^\dagger =\left [(A\diamond (B\diamond C))^T  \right ]^\dagger = \left [(A^T \diamond (B\diamond C))^T  \right ]^\dagger=  ((A^T)^\dagger \diamond ((B\diamond C)(C^TC*B^TB) ^\dagger)$

**What Can i do with $(A^T)^\dagger $?**

**the second question is if i have done correctly?**

Edit 1:

A: MxN

B: NxN

C: CxN

Comment: In your second step, you are changing $(A \diamond (B\diamond C))^T$ into $(A^T \diamond (B\diamond C))^T$. This is not correct. $(A \diamond B)^T$ is also not equal to $A^T \diamond B^T$. This only works for Kronecker products. Could you indicate the dimensions of your matrices? Does the Khatri-Rao product have full column rank?

Comment: @Florian As I understood, I can rewrite Khatri-Rao product using a Kronecker. So...why I can not use properties of Kronecker product?

Comment: You can. $A \diamond B = (A \otimes B) \cdot \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a selection matrix (equal to $I \diamond I$ btw). So $(A \diamond B)^T = ((A \otimes B) \cdot \Gamma)^T = \Gamma^T (A^T \otimes B^T)$. But that is not equal to $A^T \diamond B^T$ as you can easily verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- Transpose and pseudo inverse are interchangeable. Therefore, you can ignore the transpose, compute the pseudo inverse first, and then transpose the result.
- If a matrix has full column rank, you can expand the pseuso-inverse via $X^\dagger = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T $.
- The Khatri-Rao product satisfies $(A \diamond B)^T(A \diamond B) = (A^TA * B^TB)$. Applying this rule twice gives $(A \diamond B \diamond C)^T(A \diamond B\diamond C) = (A^TA * B^TB * C^TC)$.
- Overall, this could give something like $(A \diamond B \diamond C) \cdot (A^TA * B^TB * C^TC)^{-1}$ but whether or not this works depends on the dimensions of the matrices and on the rank of the Khatri-Rao product...
- *edit: For the dimensions you posted, a *necessary* condition would be $M \cdot C \geq N^2$.

Comment: Can I write the followin$g: (A \diamond B)= (A I \diamond B) I $ , where I is identity matrix

Comment: Sure... you just added two identity matrices, they do not change the result...